# How to get profile info by userId in asp.net mvc 3?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

I want to implement user profile, so other users will be able to see it.

How can I get profile info about a particular user by it's id in asp.net mvc3??

Comment: this Q is too vague. what kind of membership provider? what kind of database access strategy?

Comment: @Dave A asp.net mvc buit-in membership provider, and I want to access Users table if it is possible

Comment: sure, its relational database. my favorite way is to create a view of data i want and import it to my edmx file. use email as the key.

Comment: So you want to bypass the built in Profile provider? Why?

Comment: @jrummell If I use built-in Profile provider, how can I get particular user profile info?? I know only how to get current user profile

Comment: @AlekseiChepovoi see Forty-Two's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is (in a nutshell) how you would implement the default profile provider.

In your web.config, add

```
<profile>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider"
             type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider"
             connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" 
             <!--same connection string as the membership provider-->
             applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
      <properties>
        <add name="FirstName" type="string"/>
        <add name="LastName" type="string"/>
        <!--...or whatever profile properties you want/need-->
      </properties>
    </profile>
```

Then you can assign values to the profile properties

```
ProfileBase profile = ProfileBase.Create(userName);
profile["FirstName"] = "John";
profile["LastName"] = "Smith";
```

And read the values

```
string firstName;
string lastName;
ProfileBase profile = ProfileBase.Create(userName);
firstName = profile["FirstName"] as string,
lastName = profile["LastName"] as string,
```

Comment: Thanks! actually, all I was looking for was ProfileBase.Create(name) :) Anyway, the question fully describes the topic, so it will be helpfull for other users